# Extremal function as defined in the paper Graphical Models for Extremes

Tags: mathematical-statistics, extreme-value, graphical-model

The following is a question based on the paper Graphical Models for Extremes by Engelke and Hitz.

For our purposes, exponent measure is a measure defined on $[0,\infty)^d - \{0\}$ with a density $\lambda$ that satisfies

1. $\lambda(ty) = t^{-(d+1)}\lambda(y)$ for $t>0$, $y \in [0,\infty)^d - \{0\}$.
2. $\int_{y \in [0,\infty)^d - \{0\} \colon y_i > 1} \lambda(y) dy = 1$.

[image]

The extremal function at coordinate 2, relative to coordinate 1 is defined in this section.

[image]

Given a positive univariate random variable $U$ with density $f$, I see that $\lambda(y_1, y_2) = y_1^{-3} f(\frac{y_2}{y_1})$ defines a exponent measure density. But to me, it is not clear what is exactly extremal function that is being defined. Also, I can see that $\lambda(1,z)$ defines a valid density.

Later, we have this proposition:
[image]
[image]

Here $U_e$ is simply the random variable that was defined using extremal function. So my guess is that it must follow the density $\lambda_{i,j}(1,y)$, where $e = (i,j)$ is the edge.

Here, what is $Y^k$ is not important, but the right hand side apparently comes out to be

[image]

But I have no idea where $f_{U_e}(\frac{y_j}{y_i})$ is coming from. The random vector never takes the value $\frac{y_j}{y_i}$, so why would be evaluating the density at that point?

Thank you.